# Are infinitary monads monadic?

Tags: reference-request, ct.category-theory, monads, type-theory

As discussed here, [Are monads monadic?](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/19906/are-monads-monadic), in "On the monadicity of  finitary monads" by Steve Lack, the following is shown, the forgetful functor from $Mnd_f(C) \rightarrow Endo_f(C)$ is monadic, note the finitarity restrictions on both domain and codomain. In the same paper, Steve Lack, also shows a generalization for operads, but those recover only cartesian monads as discussed here [Monad arising from operad](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/66313/monad-arising-from-operad/66324#66324). Are there any results known, which generalize this to the forgetful functor $Mnd(C) \rightarrow Endo(C)$? Note the lack of finitarity restrictions.

Edit: Assume that C supports enough constructions to have internal left Kan extensions up to universes, thus guaranteeing some form of free monads. Note that for example on the universe in type theory we can take a left kan extension and then take its free monad to obtain a free monad, which exists in a higher universe. This ensures existence of arbitrary free monads at the cost of having to think about a universe.

Edit 2: To explain existence of free monad under those conditions and stop derailing the discussion away from the issue of infinitary monads, I would like to point out the construction and then write a quick argument.

```
data Lan {l1 l2 l3 : _} (G : Set l1 -> Set l2) (A : Set l3) : Set (lsuc l1 ⊔ l2 ⊔ l3) where
    FMap : {X : Set l1} -> G X  -> (X -> A) -> Lan G A
```

```
data Freer {l1 l2 l3 : _} (F : Set l1 -> Set l2) (A : Set l3) : Set (lsuc l1 ⊔ l2 ⊔ l3) where
    Pure : A -> Freer F A
    Impure : Lan F (Freer F A) → Freer F A
```

Here Lan means left kan extension of F along identity.
Note that this always exists even when the naive free monad of F does not.

Further more by algebraic-freeness of existing free monads in type theory we obtain $Talg (Freer \: F) \cong Falg (Lan \: F)$. Further by dualizing a result of Hinze we can obtain $Falg (Lan \: F) \cong Falg \: F$, for all $F$. We can actually obtain this result even when $F$ is not a strong endofunctor. (see page 2133 (26 of 52) in [Adjoint folds and unfolds—An extended study](https://www.cs.ox.ac.uk/people/ralf.hinze/publications/SCP-78-11.pdf))

Edit 3: for proofs feel free to assume any background that would be compatible with predicative HoTT or MLTT/MLTT+K and would make this property hold if it's known to turn out consistent.

Comment: First you would have to produce a free monad from any endofunctor. This is not guaranteed to exist.

Comment: @ZhenLin This is not quaranteed to exist, but it does exist under certain conditions. Normally I operate in an internal language. There the requirements are universes with existentials and internal yoneda. I will update the question to reflect these requirements.

Comment: If you restrict to accessible monad and endofunctors on a locally presentable category, the answer should be yes, but I don't know if there is a proof available in the litterature.

Comment: @SimonHenry is it that the "easy" case should be with accesssible monad on a locally presentable category? or is there some pathology that the accessibility is preventing? In the type theoretic setting I am ok with local presentability (as the type theory i have in mind really is HoTT + any amount of axioms and/or coherences that allow the monadicity to go through, as long as consistent). I am not sure whether accessibility of an arbitrary monad is reasonable I will have to give that a thought.

Comment: Those conditions are there to ensure the free monads exists and are "algebraic".

Comment: @SimonHenry Ok I think we might not be on the same page, I am interested in the forgetful functor being "algebraic" not its left adjoint. Free monads existing with respect to the forgetful functor is something I have a proof of in my setting already. What I am actually interested in is the forgetful functor being monadic.

Comment: That's not what I meant by algebraic. But i shouldn't have brought this up. let's focus on the existence of free monad. I'm not sure you can solve the problem by invoking universes. In ZFC the power set endofunctor on sets never has a free monad, even if you assume many large cardinals...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/136984/discussion-between-user4242-and-simon-henry).

Comment: @SimonHenry hopefully the edit clarifies reasons for existence of a monad which can be thought of as free even though it is not the standard one.

Comment: Not every endofunctor or monad is accessible. The power set endofunctor, for instance.

Comment: @ZhenLin yes, i guess i also need to specify that i am being a predicativist here eventually working in some form of predicative HoTT. and again is the accessibility actually necessary and what's the source for that proof?

Comment: It’s not necessary, of course. But it’s the only way we know how to construct free algebras for endofunctors in general. Anyway I don’t really buy your claim that the problem can be solved by introducing universes. I think you will have problems with  endofunctors that are polymorphic over universes.

Comment: You actually will not, there is slight issue if you think isomorphic things always have to live in the same universe. But 2 things in distinct universes can still be isomorphic.

Comment: That's not what I'm referring to. But frankly I cannot make heads or tails of your formulae so I cannot figure out if there is real mathematical argument there or not. What I know for sure is this: you can take Kan extensions of endofunctors from one universe to larger one if you like, but it may not be what you expect. For instance, if you do this procedure with the powerset endofunctor – or $[[-, 2], 2]$ if impredicative $\textrm{Prop}$ makes you unhappy – which is already defined on all universes, you will find that the extension to the larger universe is not the already-defined one.

Comment: I have proof that it does what i expect, so i would really like to stop discussing this part of assumptions and you can double check universes in the adjoint folds and unfolds, if you can point to an error in there, you are welcome, given i formalized this in agda, the error would have to lie in the application of yoneda lemma there or will be a bug in agda. Unless you can produce a proper proof or a reference rather than just random claims, i do not want to discuss this further. Note that I dont care if it's the already defined one I care that the algebra isomorphism holds.

Comment: The phrase garbage in garbage out comes to mind. I do not doubt you have a formal proof of _something_. What I doubt is that you have formalised your claim correctly. From my perspective what you have done is basically a con job: you claim that any endofunctor has a free monad, then you mutter under your breath that what you really mean is that you go up to a larger universe, extend your endofunctor, then get the free monad. I can believe that is doable – I can sketch a proof to my own satisfaction. But it proves nothing about the original endofunctor.

Comment: Related: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/365947/when-size-matters-in-category-theory-for-the-working-mathematician/365951#365951

Comment: Its f-algebras are isomorphic to f-algebras of the original endofunctor. I am not claiming that Lan f is isomorphic to the f itself or the standard free monad of that endofunctor exists. I believe proving something about f-algebras of the original endofunctor, is proving something about f, and that it does not allow me to prove arbitrary nonsense about f. I can produce properties of interest, that can not be faked by taking a left kan extension, which talk about the "freer" monad, not only its monad algebras. In my application only the monad algebras really matter.

Comment: Indeed, this extension construction – at least the one I have in my mind – will have the property that the category of algebras for the original endofunctor embeds in the category of algebras for the extended endofunctor and hence also in the category of algebras for the free monad, because the monad will be algebraically free. But the embedding is not essentially surjective, and it proves nothing about the monadicity of the original category of algebras – how could it, when there are endofunctors that have no free monad?

Comment: ok i guess i know what you are arguing against is calling that functor a left adjoint to Mnd(C) -> Endo(C), will it better to call it the left adjoint to Mnd(C) -> [ob(C),C]? Maybe i have rephrased the type theoretic property badly into categories. That does not prevent the isomorphism of categories of algebras. Note the paper proves monadicity of that forgetful functor too in the finitary case.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

These question of existence of free monad are not "derailling" the discusion. They are the whole point of the discusion. Let me clarify :

If I'm not mistaken, we have the following:

**Theorem:** Let $V$ be a monoidal category. Let $A$ be the category of monoids in $V$, then the forgetfull functor $U: A \to V$ is monadic if and only if it admits a left adjoint.

**Sketch of the Proof:** Just check the other two conditions of Beck criterion. The forgetfull functor is conservative. So we need to check that it create U-split coequalizer. Given a U-split coequalizer diagram $ X \rightrightarrows Y$ in $A$, and let $Z$ be its colimit in $V$ ( which exists by assumption). Then $Z$ comes with a monoid structure because the colimit defining it is split, so preserved by any functor, in particular the tensor product, so that $Z \otimes Z $ is the coequalizer of $X \otimes X$ and $ Y \otimes Y$ which you can use to construct an operaion $ Z \otimes Z \to Z$ making the relevant maps morphism of monoids.

With a little bit of additional work, you can conclude that this makes $Z$ a colimit in the category of monoids. $\square$

It follows that :

**Corollary:** Given $C$ any category, and $S \subset End(C)$ a full subcategory of endofunctors such that, $S$ contains the identity, is closed under composition, and every element of $S$ generates a free monads which is also in $S$, then the category of monads that are in $S$ is monadic over $S$.

**Proof:** Apply the previous result to the monoidal category $S$ (for the composition of endofunctors). $\square$

So the all point of the question is to find nice class of endofunctor for which free monads construction are available. For example :

**Proposition :** If $C$ is a locally presentable then the category of accessible monads on $C$ is monadic over the category of accessible endofunctor on $C$.

Though I have to insist that I do not know any exemple of category for which free monad construction on $C$ exists unconditionally. In fact, I'm relatively convinced this is impossible. To give an example :

**Proposition:** It is inconsistent with ZF (even with IZF) that every endofunctor of the category of sets admit a free monads.

**proof:** Consider the power-set endofunctor $X \mapsto \mathcal{P}(X)$, if the free monad on $\mathcal{P}$ existed, then as endomorphism monad exists in Set, the category of algebras for this monad would be the algebras for the endofunctor $\mathcal{P}$. In partiular the category of $\mathcal{P}-algebra$ would have an initial object, but by a well known theorem of Lambek, an initial algebra for an endofunctor $\mathcal{P}$ is always such that $\mathcal{P}(X) \simeq X$, but this is impossible by the diagonal argument. $\square$

So, unless the type theory you are using is inconsistent with ZFC, or you are using a notion of "endofunctor of sets" that does not corresponds to the usual notion, you won't be able to show that any endofunctor of the category of sets admit a free monad.

I don't quite understand what you are trying to explain with universes, but I think the problem you'll run into is that if you start form an endomorphism of the category of U-sets, then you might be able to construct something that look like a free monad on the category of V-sets for V a larger universe, but that's no longer a monad on U-set, so the forgetfull functor don't take you back to an endofunctor on U-set, but on V-set, but if you start with an endofunctor on $V$-set, then you need to go to an even larger universe W to get your free monad, but for endofunctors on W you'll need to get to a larger one and so one... And if your theory is consistent with ZFC, you can never find this way a setting where both the free monad and the forgetfull functor are simultenously defined, so that you can have a well defined "free monad monad" that acts on a category.

What will work (and maybe this is essentially what you are doing) is that if $\kappa$ is an innaccesible cardinal ( any regular cardinal actually), then any endofunctor of the category of $\kappa$-small sets can be extended into a $\kappa$-accessible endofunctor of the category of all sets, and then amongst $\kappa$-accessible endofunctors free monad constructions are available, and you can get a monadicity result by working with $\kappa$-accessible endofunctor.

Comment: I mean it is inconsistent with zfc as i am working predicatively and with internal yoneda, where the only techniques i know of exclude excluded middle, so power set functor examples are quite explicitly what fails.

Comment: Predicative doesn't mean inconsitent with ZFC. It means you are rejecting some axiom of ZFC. As long as ZFC (or a stronger theory, like ZFC + some large cardinals) proves the category of sets is a model of your theory,  you can't prove theorem inconsistant with ZFC. So unless you include axioms that are inconsitent with ZFC, you won't be able to prove this.

Comment: I think that's the internal yoneda lemma that comes from parametricity as parametricity contradicts excluded middle.

Comment: I don't know what this is. In any case, if you are indeed convince you have free monad, then I have answered your question. I just have no idea what category you are talking about - I don't know any category where every endofunctor admits a free monad - but maybe they exists

Comment: Though I should say being inconsistant with excluded middle wouldn't even be enough, the argument I gave doesn't use excluded middle, so it is already inconsitant with IZF. You basically have to be inconsistent with the existence of power set. I don't know any foundation that does this.

Comment: note izf has powerset and i am working predicatively, so i think the distinction lies in predicativity of the setting

Comment: I know. But you are still missing the point I'm making : rejecting the existence of power set isn't enough to avoid the argument - you would have to work in a system that is inconsistent with the existence of power set.

Comment: i know that the parametricity assumption contradict certain other impredicative assumptions, i will have to think how to port those to my setting to show this counterexample cannot actually go through. but this also explains why i couldnt find a generalization in the literature.

Comment: If you can use this to give an example of a non-trivial category $C$ such that every endofunctor on $C$ admit a free monad, i'd be interested to see it.